# Is there a measurable function from $[0,1]$ to $ω_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ordinals, borel-measures

Does there exist a measurable function from $[0,1]$ (with the Lebesgue measure) to $ω_1$ that induces the Dieudonné measure?

Definitions: $ω_1$ is the set of all countable ordinals, equipped with its Borel $σ$-algebra. The Dieudonné measure $\nu$ assigns measure $1$ to each subset of $ω_1$ that contains an unbounded closed set. For a measurable function $f : [0,1] \to ω_1$, the induced measure assigns measure $\mu(f^{-1}(E))$ to each measurable set $E ⊆ ω_1$.

So to restate the question, in two parts: first, is there any measurable surjection from $[0,1]$ to the set of countable ordinals? Second, is there such a function $f$ such that for each Borel set of countable ordinals $E$ that contains an unbounded closed set, $\mu(f^{1}(E)) = 1$?

Intuitively, it doesn't seem like this should be possible. For one thing, $f$ would have to map every subset $[0,1]$ with a measure other than $0$ or $1$ to a non-Borel subset of ordinals, which seems pretty pathological. The Lebesgue measure is non-atomic and regular, while the Dieudonné measure is neither. But I don't think I know enough analysis to prove it either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An equivalent formulation of your question is the following.

**Question**: Does there exist a partition $\{N_{\alpha}: \alpha < \omega_1\}$ of $[0, 1]$ into Leb. null sets such that for every $X \subseteq \omega_1$, $X$ is non-stationary iff $\bigcup \{N_{\alpha}: \alpha \in X \}$ is Leb. null.

This is clearly consistently false. For example, it fails under Martin's axiom plus the negation of CH. So the question becomes: Is this also consistently true? Shelah and I (see Theorem 1.4 [here](https://shelah.logic.at/files/205328/1208.pdf)) have the consistency of a slightly weaker statement. It is consistent that there is a (not necessarily disjoint) family $\{N_{\alpha}: \alpha < \omega_1\}$ of Leb. null subsets of $[0, 1]$ such that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_1} N_{\alpha} = [0, 1]$ and for every $X \subseteq \omega_1$, $X$ is non-stationary iff $\bigcup \{N_{\alpha}: \alpha \in X\}$ is Leb. null. But your version appears to be open.